# Javafx Timeline Listener: ObservableValue to Double

Tags: string, javafx, double, listener, observable

I am trying to add a **change listener** to a the `currentTimeProperty` of a JavaFX `Timeline`. I would like to get the value of the current time, and have it represented as a **`double`**, so that I can perform operations on that value etc.

**At the moment, this is what it looks like:**

```
public void addAnimationListener()
{
    animation.getTimeline().currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
            //double curPercentageValue = arg0.getValue(); //My attempt at trying to get the value to be a double. I tried casting it and such...
            System.out.println(arg0.getValue());
        }

    });
}
```

T**he values it prints out are e.g.:**

> 128.33333333333334 ms

...So I could just perform `String` operations to remove the `" ms"` and then use `Double.parseDouble()` to get it to the desired data type...But is there a better way? One which gets the value directly?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These things are always easier to figure out if you properly type your generic types (don't ignore compiler/IDE warnings):

```
public static void addAnimationListener()
{
    animation.getTimeline().currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>(){
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) {
            double millis = newValue.toMillis();
            System.out.println(millis + " ms");
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need @James_D. I'm sorry, I am quite new to implementing some of this stuff, and so it didn't even occur to me that I could change the generic types. It works exactly as hoped now. Regards, Ben.